# Creating new objects for a recursive class instance with multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion

Lets say there is a class A and an instance of it `classA`, class A has four sub-classes named a11,a12,a21 and a22.

A's constructor creates a11,a12,a21,a22 in separate-threads with help of Parallel.For.

```
//interior of A
A A11;
A A12;
A A21;
A A22;

public A()
{
    Parallel.For(0,4,i=>
    {
         if(i==0) {A11= new A(/*recursion limit parameter*/);}
         if(i==1) {A12= new A(/*recursion limit parameter*/);}
         if(i==2) {A21= new A(/*recursion limit parameter*/);}
         if(i==3) {A22= new A(/*recursion limit parameter*/);}
    });
}
```

**Question:** Is there %100 certainity that A11..A22 will not be destroyed when Parallel.For exits?

Example:

1)main thread initiates constructor.

2)Parallel.For starts four concurrent threads.

3)Four threads get their copies of class A(which is not created yet, how can they work concurrently?)

4)Each one of them create a new object(seen only by creator thread?) in their own copy

5)Parallel.for ends

which copy is chosen to be used? If all are created truly, then this must be a serial action. But creation time decreases when parallel.for is used.

A11..A22 have four components too, this goes deeper until a limit is reached recursively.

Thanks.

Comment: How about posting a self-contained minimal code? this would also help you to get the answers.

Comment: You mean the real code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: Is there %100 certainity that A11..A22 will not be destroyed when Parallel.For exits?

Absolutely. They're reachable within the newly-created object. This bit is your logical mistake:

> Four threads get their copies of class A(which is not created yet, how can they work concurrently?)

They don't. The four threads (if indeed there *are* four threads) will all be using `this` - the instance has been created, just not fully initialized yet (the constructor hasn't completed). Code can still *use* an object whose constructor hasn't completed yet - you just need to be careful when doing so.